# Sending array or session values in an email message

Tags: asp-classic

I have an array holding values and that array is in a session.
I want to send the values of that array in an HTML formatted email.

I am not able to figure out how to create an HTML message with dynamic values and set the HTML message to `CDOSYSMail` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to review these:

Send an email:
http://w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp

Embed ASP into HTML:
http://www.maconstateit.net/tutorials/ASP/ASP02/asp02-01.asp

and in general:
http://www.maconstateit.net/tutorials/ASP/

Comment: Thanks, I have gone through these. However my requirment is that i need to create HTML based on dynamic values and then set it like myMail.HTMLBody = "<h1>This is a message.</h1>" <---- here my dynamically created HTML will come. Now i am not sure how to generate that

Comment: I think i have got the answer in your last link!! thank you

Comment: Can you please expand on the last link within your answer? Again, answers that just contain links are a big problem on Stack Overflow, especially if they are the accepted answer. When links break (it happens quite frequently), the answers aren't helpful anymore.

Comment: The last link (accepted answer by the OP) is a complete set of tutorials on the subject of ASP.  How do I expand that into an answer ?

Comment: @Dee: You can't. If your answer really is "Read the documentation," then the question is too localized. I'll close it; we're not a proxy for Google. Did you read the link I provided you?:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022

Comment: But he was helped.  Something is not right when you deny help.  I'm sorry, that just seems wrong to me.